# Firebase combining conditions by OR statement

Tags: firebase, conditional-statements, where-clause

I am looking for a way to combine where conditions by OR statement. Let's assume I have a query:

```
.database()
    .ref("myPath").orderByChild("category").equalTo("main")
    .once("value")
    .then()
```

I would like to get all the objects, that contains property "category", which is equal to "main "OR "other". I know I could do the loop and evaluate this query multiple times and concatenate the results, but this does not seems to be the efficient way. Anyone knows the best way to do that?

Comment: I am not sure if you could add one more `.equalTo("other")` right next to first one.
but just try once and let me know.

Comment: Tried that already, that's not working. Only one .equalTo is acceptable.

Comment: Yes, "you can combine multiple limit or range functions" as explained in the documentation, see  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data but not with equalTo

Comment: Indeed, multiple .equalTo raises an exception.

Comment: You want to query for two values. Is "other" one of these value all the time? I mean are you going to query for "abc" or "other", "xyz" or "other" or you may query for "abc" or "xyz" (without "other")?

Comment: No, it's not all the time "other", this is only certain example. I want to implement filtering mechanism, so there can be multiple conditions and many OR statements.